# Query performance depends on parameter value

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.5, query-performance

In the system I'm working with there are many type hierarchies, where each type  corresponds to a table. For example `f_dp_rkkbase -> f_dp_rkk -> f_dp_inputrkk`. To distinguish between different types in parent tables there is an additional `id_type` column, for example all rows in `f_dp_inputrkk` table have `id_type = 5419`, and all `f_dp_rkk` entries which are `f_dp_inputrkk` also have this `id_type = 5419`. Now consider this simple query:

```
explain analyze
select * 
FROM f_dp_inputrkk inputrkk
JOIN f_dp_rkk rkk ON rkk.id = inputrkk.id
JOIN f_dp_rkkbase rkkbase ON rkkbase.id = rkk.id
WHERE
rkk.regnumcnt IS NOT NULL 
and
rkkbase.isdeleted <> 1 and (rkkbase.module = 179 AND rkkbase.module_type = 1015)
order by rkk.regnumcnt desc, rkk.id desc 
limit 51
```

```
"Limit  (cost=1.28..7853.98 rows=51 width=1725) (actual time=3408.360..3441.328 rows=51 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.28..1620274.15 rows=10523 width=1725) (actual time=3408.359..3441.317 rows=51 loops=1)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..1604032.72 rows=34012 width=1098) (actual time=3408.346..3440.990 rows=51 loops=1)"
"              ->  Index Scan Backward using i5405l92mq0nfig5eva9bjg2ea on f_dp_rkk rkk  (cost=0.43..236699.92 rows=2136320 width=201) (actual time=0.016..839.021 rows=581494 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (regnumcnt IS NOT NULL)"
"              ->  Index Scan using pk_5392 on f_dp_rkkbase rkkbase  (cost=0.43..0.63 rows=1 width=897) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=581494)"
"                    Index Cond: (id = rkk.id)"
"                    Filter: ((isdeleted <> 1) AND (module = 179) AND (module_type = 1015))"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
"        ->  Index Scan using pk_5419 on f_dp_inputrkk inputrkk  (cost=0.42..0.47 rows=1 width=627) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=51)"
"              Index Cond: (id = rkk.id)"
"Planning time: 1.208 ms"
```

When I change `rkkbase.module = 179` to `rkkbase.module = 171` the query runs much faster:

```
"Limit  (cost=1.28..1515.24 rows=51 width=1725) (actual time=116.943..140.879 rows=51 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.28..1679871.94 rows=56589 width=1725) (actual time=116.942..140.865 rows=51 loops=1)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..1256836.72 rows=660950 width=828) (actual time=1.832..117.051 rows=7036 loops=1)"
"              ->  Index Scan Backward using i5405l92mq0nfig5eva9bjg2ea on f_dp_rkk rkk  (cost=0.43..236699.92 rows=2136320 width=201) (actual time=0.019..13.655 rows=17321 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (regnumcnt IS NOT NULL)"
"              ->  Index Scan using pk_5419 on f_dp_inputrkk inputrkk  (cost=0.42..0.47 rows=1 width=627) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=17321)"
"                    Index Cond: (id = rkk.id)"
"        ->  Index Scan using pk_5392 on f_dp_rkkbase rkkbase  (cost=0.43..0.63 rows=1 width=897) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=7036)"
"              Index Cond: (id = rkk.id)"
"              Filter: ((isdeleted <> 1) AND (module = 171) AND (module_type = 1015))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
"Planning time: 1.382 ms"
```

How can I make the first query run as fast as the second? I've tried to fool PostgreSQL with additional criteria `and rkk.id_type = 5419`:

```
explain analyze
select * 
FROM f_dp_inputrkk inputrkk
JOIN f_dp_rkk rkk ON rkk.id = inputrkk.id
JOIN f_dp_rkkbase rkkbase ON rkkbase.id = rkk.id
WHERE
rkk.regnumcnt IS NOT NULL 
and
rkkbase.isdeleted <> 1 and (rkkbase.module = 179 AND rkkbase.module_type = 1015) and rkk.id_type = 5419
order by regnumcnt desc, rkk.id desc 
limit 51
```

```
"Limit  (cost=1.28..12471.47 rows=51 width=1725) (actual time=3968.748..4002.631 rows=51 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.28..805428.78 rows=3294 width=1725) (actual time=3968.747..4002.612 rows=51 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: (rkk.id = rkkbase.id)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..598129.24 rows=206921 width=828) (actual time=0.052..2709.946 rows=274681 loops=1)"
"              ->  Index Scan Backward using i5405l92mq0nfig5eva9bjg2ea on f_dp_rkk rkk  (cost=0.43..242040.72 rows=668810 width=201) (actual time=0.031..963.060 rows=274681 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (regnumcnt IS NOT NULL)"
"                    Filter: (id_type = 5419)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 306813"
"              ->  Index Scan using pk_5419 on f_dp_inputrkk inputrkk  (cost=0.42..0.52 rows=1 width=627) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=274681)"
"                    Index Cond: (id = rkk.id)"
"        ->  Index Scan using pk_5392 on f_dp_rkkbase rkkbase  (cost=0.43..0.99 rows=1 width=897) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=274681)"
"              Index Cond: (id = inputrkk.id)"
"              Filter: ((isdeleted <> 1) AND (module = 179) AND (module_type = 1015))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
"Planning time: 2.202 ms"
"Execution time: 4003.603 ms"
```

This plan is almost the same as the second, but at the same time the query is as slow as the first. `ANALYZE` is run regularly. And there are more records with `module = 171` (195456) than with `module = 179` (39189), so the first query should be more efficient!

How can I optimize the query?

**Update**
Create table statements

```
CREATE TABLE public.f_dp_rkkbase
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  id_type integer,
  created_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  module bigint NOT NULL,
  module_type integer NOT NULL,
  isdeleted smallint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_5392 PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_5392_0 FOREIGN KEY (id_type)
      REFERENCES public.domain_object_type_id (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_5392_2 FOREIGN KEY (module, module_type)
      REFERENCES public.ss_module (id, id_type) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT u_5392_0 UNIQUE (id, id_type),
  CONSTRAINT f_dp_rkkbase_isdeleted_check CHECK (isdeleted = ANY (ARRAY[0, 1]))
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX i539267o9haifgo7fkm41bqlo0
  ON public.f_dp_rkkbase
  USING btree
  (created_date);

CREATE INDEX i5392fpl9igvb7r408k7qb4nll
  ON public.f_dp_rkkbase
  USING btree
  (created_date DESC, id DESC);

CREATE INDEX i5392i66afgasmbugcrg4fneu
  ON public.f_dp_rkkbase
  USING btree
  (created_date, id DESC);

CREATE INDEX i5392sh1hhcs97qvc4idnmh2s4
  ON public.f_dp_rkkbase
  USING btree
  (created_date, id);

CREATE INDEX i_5392_1
  ON public.f_dp_rkkbase
  USING btree
  (module);
```

```
CREATE TABLE public.f_dp_rkk
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  id_type integer,
  regnumprist character varying(253),
  regnumcnt bigint,
  regnumfin character varying(253),
  CONSTRAINT pk_5405 PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_5405_0 FOREIGN KEY (id)
      REFERENCES public.f_dp_rkkworegandctrl (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_5405_1 FOREIGN KEY (id_type)
      REFERENCES public.domain_object_type_id (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT u_5405_0 UNIQUE (id, id_type)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX i54059563c1a1idf5fsgol0f5k
  ON public.f_dp_rkk
  USING btree
  (regdate, id);

CREATE INDEX i54059s954qekn3e74r0om045
  ON public.f_dp_rkk
  USING btree
  (regnumcnt);

CREATE INDEX i5405l92mq0nfig5eva9bjg2ea
  ON public.f_dp_rkk
  USING btree
  (regnumcnt, id);

CREATE INDEX i5405m3otpf6bpch692dqsds4
  ON public.f_dp_rkk
  USING btree
  (((COALESCE(regnumprist, ''::character varying)::text || COALESCE(regnumcnt::character varying, ''::character varying)::text) || COALESCE(regnumfin, ''::character varying)::text) COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX i5405olaq2658pgcmhljbs0t6b
  ON public.f_dp_rkk
  USING btree
  (regnumcnt DESC, id DESC);
```

```
CREATE TABLE public.f_dp_inputrkk
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  id_type integer,
  CONSTRAINT pk_5419 PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_5419_0 FOREIGN KEY (id)
      REFERENCES public.f_dp_rkk (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_5419_1 FOREIGN KEY (id_type)
      REFERENCES public.domain_object_type_id (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT u_5419_0 UNIQUE (id, id_type),
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

**Update 2**

`order by regnumcnt+0 desc, rkk.id desc`

```
"Limit  (cost=83197.83..83197.96 rows=51 width=1725) (actual time=643.584..643.601 rows=51 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=83197.83..83224.14 rows=10523 width=1725) (actual time=643.584..643.598 rows=51 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: ((rkk.regnumcnt + 0)) DESC, inputrkk.id DESC"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 74kB"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=53494.34..82846.76 rows=10523 width=1725) (actual time=130.436..576.567 rows=37317 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=53493.91..74669.15 rows=11147 width=1524) (actual time=130.395..391.890 rows=37457 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (inputrkk.id = rkkbase.id)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on f_dp_inputrkk inputrkk  (cost=0.00..18439.38 rows=699838 width=627) (actual time=0.012..79.238 rows=699871 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=53043.75..53043.75 rows=36013 width=897) (actual time=63.952..63.952 rows=37652 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11476kB"
"                          ->  Index Scan using i_5392_1 on f_dp_rkkbase rkkbase  (cost=0.43..53043.75 rows=36013 width=897) (actual time=0.039..46.228 rows=37652 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (module = 179)"
"                                Filter: (isdeleted = 0)"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 1742"
"              ->  Index Scan using pk_5405 on f_dp_rkk rkk  (cost=0.43..0.72 rows=1 width=201) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=37457)"
"                    Index Cond: (id = inputrkk.id)"
"                    Filter: (regnumcnt IS NOT NULL)"
"                    Rows Removed by Filter: 0"
"Planning time: 1.699 ms"
"Execution time: 643.919 ms"
```

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the output of `\dt table_name` for all 3 tables?

Comment: Also, is there an index on `(module_type, module)`? And what are the possible values of `isdeleted`? Are they only 0 and 1 or more?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ `CONSTRAINT fk_5392_2 FOREIGN KEY (module, module_type)
      REFERENCES public.ss_module (id, id_type) MATCH SIMPLE` and yes, isdeleted is either 0 or 1.

Comment: OK, good but that's a `FOREIGN KEY`. Is there also an index on this column combination or just the fK?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ only the FK.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ sorry, I'm not using psql, but PgAdmin, don't know what `\dt` does. Do you need description of all fields and indices for all 3 tables?

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` statements would be ok (and you could remove unrelated columns). (`\dt` shows that plus indexes)

Comment: If you change the ORDER BY clause to `order by (regnumcnt +0) desc, rkk.id desc`, do you get a faster execution?  If so, can you post the EXPLAIN ANALYZE of it?

Comment: @jjanes yes, now the query runs faster, but it also requires more memory, I think.

Comment: Memory is there to be used, so this is not necessarily a problem.  If you post an EXPLAIN ANALYZE of it, we could maybe use the info it contains to figure out a better plan yet.

Comment: @jjanes but I've already updated my question, see the second update. There is `Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 11476kB` line.

Comment: @pocketgulag Sorry, it auto-refreshed to show your comment, but not your edit. I don't think 11 MB is bad memory usage for a query like this.  Without re-organizing your data so that regnumcnt appears in the same table as module and module_type, I don't think you will be able to do much better.  Walking the index in regnumcnt desc order will be better for modules which have a lot of high regnumcnt, but those without a lot of high regnumcnt will suffer.

Answer (score 2):

Several notes that seem obvious, even without knowing the exact `CREATE TABLE` statements:

- `f_dp_rkk` or `rkk` table and :

  ```
   WHERE
   rkk.regnumcnt IS NOT NULL 
   - ...
   ORDER BY rkk.regnumcnt DESC, rkk.id DESC
  ```

  This will likely  be good fit for a partial index:

  ```
   (regnumcnt, id) WHERE (regnumcnt IS NOT NULL)
  ```
- `f_dp_rkkbase` or `rkkbase` table:

  ```
  WHERE
      rkkbase.isdeleted <> 1 
  AND (rkkbase.module = 179 AND rkkbase.module_type = 1015)
  ```

  There are several things that can be done here:

  - An index on `(module, module_type)` as you have a `FOREIGN KEY` to `module` (but not yet, see below).
  - Using `rkkbase.isdeleted = 0` instead of `rkkbase.isdeleted <> 1`. The optimizer can't know that there are only 2 values available in the column and equality `=` is better than inequality `<>`.
  - Even better if you can change the type of the column (from `int` or `smallint` that it is now) to `BOOLEAN`, which would have only 2 possible values `TRUE` or `FALSE`). Then we can use `rkkbase.isdeleted = FALSE` or just `(NOT rkkbase.isdeleted)`
  - Improve the index more with a 3-composite one:

    ```
    (module, module_type, isdeleted)
    ```

  or, if the condition is always `rkkbase.isdeleted <> 1` (and never `= 1`), with a partial index (see several options, depending on the column type and how you plan to write the query):

  ```
      (module, module_type) WHERE (isdeleted <> 1)  -- for current query

      (module, module_type) WHERE (isdeleted = 0)   -- if you change the query 

      (module, module_type) WHERE (NOT isdeleted)   -- if BOOLEAN
  ```
- Further improvements: depending on whether there are `FOREIGN KEY` constraints between the 3 tables (and which direction they point), you could change one or both `INNER` joins to `LEFT` joins. This allows in some cases the optimizer to avoid some plans or move a join for a later phase of the plan or even eliminate a join altogether.

Comment: Just updated my question. I was wrong there is an index on `module`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I really should post `create table` statements earlier. There is already an index on `(regnumcnt, id)`, and on `module` Tried `isdeleted = 0` and replacing joins with left joins, the plan is almost the same. Condition also can be `isdeleted = 1` for some queries.

Comment: I'm not sure if a `(regnumcnt, id) WHERE (regnumcnt IS NOT NULL)` or an `(id, regnumcnt) WHERE (regnumcnt IS NOT NULL)` would perform better. I'll check the CREATE TABLE statemets and update my answer.

Comment: Did you try adding the composite index `(module, module_type, isdeleted)` and was there any difference in performance / plan (was the index used)?

Comment: Just tried to add this index, and it also was not used. But I've found that if I comment `regnumcnt is null` condition, the query execution is fast regardless of module.

Comment: I mean `regnumcnt is not null` condition. If the condition is `regnumcnt is null` the query is more efficient too.